# How is it possible for the yugas such as Dwapar and Kali to be personified in human-like form?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, puranas

It is mentioned at many places that they were present in human forms, it doesn't make sense.

Like in Kalki Puran, it us shown that Satyug in human form is with Lord Kalki.

Also, in Dwapar Yug,Kali is making conversations with Dwapar about getting late for Damyanti swayamvar.

Comment: Not just yugas are personified, even diseases, rivers, mountains, sounds, etc are personified. This might be done to greatly emphasize how they are in simpler notation, or maybe there is something beyond? Actually it's a nice question.